# How to create a nested object from data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular-cli

**Before**

This is an object with multiple rows:

```
  {
  "functions": [
    {
      "package_id": "2",
      "module_id": "2",
      "data_id": "2"
    },
    {
      "package_id": "1",
      "module_id": "1",
      "data_id": "2"
    },
    {
      "package_id": "2",
      "module_id": "3",
      "data_id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired result**

I want this to return into a "nested" Object like below, without duplicates:

```
{
  "packages": [
    {
      "package_id": "2",
      "modules": [
        {
          "module_id": "2",
          "data": [
            {
              "data_id": "2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "module_id": "3",
          "data": [
            {
              "data_id": "3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },{
      "package_id": "1",
      "modules": [
        {
          "module_id": "1",
          "data": [
            {
              "data_id": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've already tried loops inside loops, with constructing multiple arrays and objects. Which causes duplicates or overriding objects into single ones. Is there a more generic way to generate this with JavaScript? (It's for an Angular (6) project.

**Example 1**

```
getFunctionPackage() {

        var fList = this.functionList;

        var dArr = [];
        var dObj = {};

        var pArr = [];
        var pObj = {};

        var mArr = [];
        var mObj = {};

        for (var key in fList) {

            pObj['package_id'] = fList[key]['package_id'];
            mObj['module_id'] = fList[key]['module_id'];
            dObj['data_id'] = fList[key]['data_id'];

            for (var i = 0; i < pArr.length; i++) {
                if (pArr[i].package_id != pObj['package_id']) {
                    pArr.push(pObj);
                }
                for (var x = 0; x < mArr.length; x++) {
                    if (pArr[i]['modules'][x].module_id != mObj['module_id']) {
                        mArr.push(mObj);
                    }
                    for (var y = 0; y < dArr.length; y++) {
                        if (pArr[i]['modules'][x]['datas'][y].data_id != dObj['data_id']) {
                            dArr.push(dObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (dArr.length == 0) {
                dArr.push(dObj);
            }
            mObj['datas'] = dArr;

            if (mArr.length == 0) {
                mArr.push(mObj);
            }
            pObj['modules'] = mArr;

            if (pArr.length == 0) {
                pArr.push(pObj);
            }
            dObj = {};
            mObj = {};
            pObj = {};
        }
    }
```

**Example 2:**
Results in skipping cause of the booleans

```
 var fList = this.functionList;

var dArr = [];
var dObj = {};

var pArr = [];
var pObj = {};

var mArr = [];
var mObj = {};

var rObj = {};

for (var key in fList) {

    pObj['package_id'] = fList[key]['package_id'];
    mObj['module_id'] = fList[key]['module_id'];
    dObj['data_id'] = fList[key]['data_id'];

    var pfound = false;
    var mfound = false;
    var dfound = false;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < pArr.length; i++) {
        if (pArr[i].package_id == pObj['package_id']) {
            for (var x = 0; x < mArr.length; x++) {
                if (pArr[i]['modules'][x].module_id == mObj['module_id']) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < dArr.length; y++) {
                        if (pArr[i]['modules'][x]['datas'][y].data_id == dObj['data_id']) {
                            dfound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    mfound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            pfound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!dfound) {
        dArr.push(dObj);
        mObj['datas'] = dArr;
        dObj = {};
    }

    if (!mfound) {
        mArr.push(mObj);
        pObj['modules'] = mArr;
        mObj = {};
    }

    if (!pfound) {
        pArr.push(pObj);
        pObj = {};
    }

    dArr = [];
    mArr = [];
}

rObj['packages'] = pArr;
console.log(rObj);
```

Comment: `I've already tried loops inside loops` than add the tried code too in question

Comment: More generic than what? You haven't shown any code at all. It is expected for you to show attempts to solve your own issue and people here help you fix them. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl Absolutely right! I've added 2 try-outs too the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more generic approach using `Array#reduce()` to create  a grouped object based on the package id as keys. You can use any loop to build this same object ...`for()` or `forEach()` for example.

Then use `Object.values()` to get the final array from that grouped object

Using methods like `Array#find()` simplifies traversing to see if a module exists already or not within each package

```js
const grouped = data.functions.reduce((a, c )=>{

   // if group object doesn't exist - create it or use existing one
   a[c.package_id] =  a[c.package_id] || {package_id : c.package_id, modules: [] }
   
   // store reference to the group modules array
   const mods = a[c.package_id].modules
   
   // look within that group modules array to see if module object exists
   let module = mods.find(mod => mod.module_id === c.module_id)

   if(!module){
      // or create new module object
      module = {module_id: c.module_id, data:[]}
      // and push it into modules array
      mods.push(module);
   } 

   // push new data object to module data array
   module.data.push({data_id: c.data_id})
   
   return a

}, {})


// create final results object
const res = { packages : Object.values(grouped) }

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
  const data = {
    "functions": [{
        "package_id": "2",
        "module_id": "2",
        "data_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "package_id": "1",
        "module_id": "1",
        "data_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "package_id": "2",
        "module_id": "3",
        "data_id": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Note I assumed that `data_id` are not duplicated per package_id/module_id. Would be an easy conditional to check if they may have duplicates in original data before last step in the `reduce()`